How to get access to PrintWriter from AgentBase in a Java script library in Domino via LS2J
I've got a web agent that runs in lotusscript but it needs to call a java method via LS2J. The purpose is to print out some content and I need access to the printwriter for that. The docmentation points me to using getAgentOutput() however this throws a null pointer exception. The class is structured as follows:
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import lotus.domino.*;

public class WebPrinter extends AgentBase {
    public boolean printFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            PrintWriter pw = getAgentOutput();  <--- error here
            ...
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }

The lotusscript that calls it is as follows:
Use "JavaWebCode"
Dim jSession As New JavaSession
Dim jClass As JavaClass
Dim jObject As JavaObject

Set jClass = jSession.Getclass("com.test.WebPrinter")
Set jObject = jClass.Createobject()

result = jObject.printFile(fileName)
...

The error is:

java.lang.NullPointerException at
lotus.domino.AgentBase.getAgentOutput (unknown source)

How to I get access to the PrintWriter outside a Java agent? I don't really want to refactor the lotusscript agent to Java if I can.
Thanks all.

To the person who's voted to close on the basis this needs more details or clarity. What do you need? I'll edit the question.

AgentBase is not going to be available to a LotusScript agent through LS2J. You are getting a null pointer error because the AgentBase class itself is not instantiated. It is only instantiated when the server starts a Java agent.
I'm not aware of any other way to get access to the PrintWriter, so what I'd do is pass the output back to the LotusScript code and have it generate the output.
